Console error with sweetalert2 plugin from adminlte and primefaces
I have a problem when I press the primefaces button to delete a client:

Here is my javascript code with the button calling the function.
Javascript:
if (window.location.pathname.endsWith('/cliente.xhtml')) {

function confirmarEliminar() {
    Swal.fire({
        title: "<strong>HTML <u>example</u></strong>",
        icon: "info",
        html: `
You can use <b>bold text</b>,
<a href="#">links</a>,
and other HTML tags `,showCloseButton: true,
        showCancelButton: true,
        focusConfirm: false,
        confirmButtonText: `
<i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i> Great! `,confirmButtonAriaLabel: "Thumbs up, great!",
        cancelButtonText: `
<i class="fa fa-thumbs-down"></i>  `,cancelButtonAriaLabel: "Thumbs down"
    });
}};

And the button.
<p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-close" onclick="confirmarEliminar()"></p:commandButton>

I would also like to know how to execute a function to the controller when the user presses OK.
